# CSS 3 background-size not working on IE9

Tags: css

`background-image:url(yellow.jpg);
background-size:180px 180px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;`

The above mentioned css works perfect on chrome but **ie9** is unable to scale images + display images correctly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure your IE runs in IE9 mode? Your code works with any image I tried.

(F12 to open developer window)

Comment: Gah. Good find. I spent longer than I'd care to admit chasing this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is based on scaling the image to the proper size. Have you tried this?

```
background:url(yellow.jpg) 0 0 / 180px 180px no-repeat fixed;
```

Basically what it does is:

background:background-image background-position(top) background-position(left) / background-size(height) background-size(width) background-repeat background-attachment;

That should work with IE9 (and all other modern browsers out there) ...

Answer (score 0):

IE will open a page without the doctype tag in quirks mode in which background-size does nothing. To force IE to open the page in IE9 mode add <!doctype html> at the top of each html document.