# Background image isn't displayed correctly in IE 9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, background-image

I am building a html 5 site and it works fine in chrome and Firefox.  When I launch it in IE 9 everything works except my background image it doesn't span the height of the site.  My css for the body is below and this controls the background image and its height and width.

```
#faq_page { 
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 0 auto;
    background: #9c182f url(../images/faqimage.jpg) no-repeat center;
    background-size: 1350px 1700px;
    margin-top: auto; 
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776580/css-3-background-size-not-working-on-ie9

Comment: tried that and the image doesnt center, as soon as I add center the image and the bg color disapears

Answer (score 0):

[This example](http://jsbin.com/ulewej/1/edit) seems to work on my IE9.

Make sure your IE is actually in IE9 mode:

[image]

Comment: tried all the examples above and they dont work.  either the image doesnt display or only the background color does.

Comment: if i have the following code everything works but the image isnt in the center `#faq_page{ 
 margin: 0 auto ; width: 1024px ; height: 100% ; padding-top: 0 auto ; background:#9c182f url(../images/faqimage.jpg) 0 0 / 1350px 1700px no-repeat fixed; margin-top: auto; 
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try to set this in your head:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

Comment: no doesnt seem to do anything.  I notice that it seems to cut the image.  In chrime the full image is dispplayed whereas ie cuts the top off